# passing comparator to priority_queue declared as class member

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, stl, priority-queue

I got stuck when I tried to use priority_queue as class member. Please see the code below and let me know why L1 is not able to see the Type but L2 is able to see. I tried struct and also putting ctor.

If this is the way the things work, will it be possible to declare the priority_queue as class member and pass the comparator at a later time, from inside the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class comprLess
{
    public:
            bool operator() (int p1, int p2)
            {
                return true;
            }
};


    class Something
    {
        public:
            comprLess cLess;

            //L1           
            priority_queue<int, vector<int>, comprLess> pq(cLess);  
            //Gives compilation error "syntax error: identifier 'cLess'"

            void Method()
            {
                //L2 
                priority_queue<int, vector<int>, comprLess> pq2(cLess); 
                //works fine
            }
    };
```

Comment: `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, comprLess> pq{cLess};` Note braces in place of parentheses.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, `comrLess::operator()` does not meet the requirements of a strict weak ordering, and thus is not a valid comparison predicate.

Comment: Thanks Igor.  Your suggestion worked. I have to read up about strick weak ordering.

Answer (score 0):

L1 is not able to see cLess because it hasn't been constructed yet; you are at the class definition stage. L2 is called when the class is already instantiated.

You used an incorrect syntax. You need to change brackets.

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, comprLess> pq{cLess};
```

That causes initialisation of the priority queue at construction time.
Alternatively you may construct the queue in the class constructor.

```
Something() : pq(cLess) {}
```

Comment: Thanks dmitri.  Your suggestion worked. I should have thought about initializor list myself.